# jquery - how to check if element has any classes attached to it

Tags: jquery

you would imagine this would be easy to implement, but oh well..

anyway, I have an element to which classes are added or removed based of interaction on the site.

I can easily check if object has a specific class, using `$(element).hasClass("myClass")`

but how do I check if the element has any classes attached to it without knowing their names. Something like:

```
$("#mydiv").hasAtLeastOneClassPresent
{
 do this
}
$("#mydiv").hasNotASingleClass
{
 do that
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the `classList` property:

```
$("#mydiv").prop('classList').length
```

Or, with the DOM:

```
document.querySelector('#mydiv').classList.length
```

If the length is zero it has no classes, if it's greater than zero it has that number of classes.

With the DOM as a function:

```
// a named function to take a DOM node:
function hasClasses(node) {

  // returns a Boolean, true if the length
  // of the Array-like Element.classList is
  // greater than 0, false otherwise:
  return node.classList.length > 0;
}

var elem = document.getElementById('mydiv');

if (hasClasses(elem)) {
  elem.classList.add('found');
}
```

```js
function hasClasses(node) {
  return node.classList.length > 0;
}

var elem1 = document.getElementById('mydiv'),
  elem2 = document.getElementById('myotherdiv');

if (hasClasses(elem1)) {
  elem1.classList.add('found');
}

if (hasClasses(elem2)) {
  elem2.classList.add('found');
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 2em;
  border: 3px solid limegreen;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em 0;
}
.found {
  border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" class="hasAClass"></div>
<div id="myotherdiv"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wkLfzjam/2/).

In the event of a browser that doesn't feature the `element.classList` interface, you could instead use `className`:

```
// retrieving the specified element,
// retrieving its 'className' property,
// removing the leading and trailing white-space,
// retrieving the length of the trimmed string,
// checking that this length is greater than 0:
$("#mydiv").prop('className').trim().length > 0;
```

```js
var div1 = $("#mydiv"),
  div2 = $('#myotherdiv'),
  div1HasClassName = div1.prop('className').trim().length > 0,
  div2HasClassName = div2.prop('className').trim().length > 0;

// Boolean true:
if (div1HasClassName) {
  div1.addClass('found');
}

// Boolean false:
if (div2HasClassName.length > 0) {
  div2.addClass('found');
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 2em;
  border: 3px solid limegreen;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em 0;
}
.found {
  border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" class="a"></div>
<div id="myotherdiv"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wkLfzjam/4/).

Or, with the DOM:

```
// retrieving the element with the id of 'mydiv'
// (or null if no such element exists),
// retrieving the className, as a String, of the element,
// removing the leading and trailing white-space,
// retrieving the length of the String,
// evaluating whether the length is greater than 0;
// returning a Boolean true if so, false if not:
document.querySelector("#mydiv").className.trim().length > 0;
```

```js
var div1 = document.querySelector("#mydiv"),
  div2 = document.querySelector('#myotherdiv'),
  div1HasClassName = div1.className.trim().length > 0,
  div2HasClassName = div2.className.trim().length > 0;

// Boolean true:
if (div1HasClassName) {
  div1.className += ' found';
}

// Boolean false:
if (div2HasClassName) {
  div2.className += ' found';
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 2em;
  border: 3px solid limegreen;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em 0;
}
.found {
  border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" class="a"></div>
<div id="myotherdiv"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wkLfzjam/5/).

It's also possible to write a (*very*) simple jQuery selector to select only those elements that have classes, this selector takes *no* arguments:

```
// defining the selector-name 'hasClasses':
$.expr[':'].hasClasses = function(

  // this is the current element of the collection over
  // which the selector iterates:
  objNode
) {

  // here we return true, if:
  //   the current node has a 'class' attribute, and
  //   has a classList (though this could be substituted
  //   for className for backwards compatibility), and
  //   the classList.length is greater than zero
  // Otherwise returning false:
  return objNode.hasAttribute('class') && objNode.classList && objNode.classList.length > 0;
};


$('div:hasClasses').addClass('found');
```

```js
$.expr[':'].hasClasses = function(
  objNode
) {
  return objNode.hasAttribute('class') && objNode.classList && objNode.classList.length > 0;
};


$('div:hasClasses').addClass('found');
```

```css
div {
  height: 2em;
  border: 3px solid limegreen;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em 0;
}
.found {
  border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class></div>
<div class="hasAClass"></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div></div>
<div class="hasAClass"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wkLfzjam/6).

Or, similarly, a jQuery plugin that also takes no arguments:

```
// using an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE),
// to immediately run the function as soon as it's encountered:
(function($) {

  // defining the plugin name ('hasClasses'):
  $.fn.hasClasses = function() {

    // 'this', here, is the jQuery collection
    // over which we're iterating with filter():
    return this.filter(function() {

      // we're using this node potentially three times,
      // so we cache it here for simplicity ('this,' within
      // the filter() method, is the DOM node):
      var objNode = this;

      // if the following assessment returns true the
      // current node is retained in the collection and
      // and retained for chaining, if it evaluates to
      // false it's discarded from the collection and so
      // not retained/returned:
      return objNode.hasAttribute('class') && objNode.classList && objNode.classList.length > 0;
    });
  };

// passing in jQuery to allow the use of the $ alias
// within the IIFE:
})(jQuery);

// calling the plugin:
$('div').hasClasses().addClass('found');
```

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.hasClasses = function() {
    return this.filter(function() {
      var objNode = this;
      return objNode.hasAttribute('class') && objNode.classList && objNode.classList.length > 0;
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('div').hasClasses().addClass('found');
```

```css
div {
  height: 2em;
  border: 3px solid limegreen;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em 0;
}
.found {
  border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class></div>
<div class="hasAClass"></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div></div>
<div class="hasAClass"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wkLfzjam/1/).

Comment: `$("#mydiv").prop('className').split(/\s+/).length;`   and  `document.querySelector('#mydiv').className.split(/\s+/).length` wont work if there is no class attribute in DOM ,,

Comment: With pure JS: `document.querySelector('#mydiv').className`, with jQuery: `$("#mydiv")[0].className` - both will be truthy if element has any class set

Comment: To both the above, corrected just now; removed the use of `split()`.

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery:

```
if($("#mydiv").is('[class]')
```

As [YoYo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5336818/yo-yo) points it out in comment, this would failed if attribute class as an empty string set. So don't use it...

Comment: Woah man... You are telling me new new things. `:)` Shit right! This is CSS.

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed to admit I hadn't thought of that >.< do bear in mind that it is possible to have an empty attribute value for the class attribute.

Comment: @DavidThomas Feel free to edit your answer to include it and makes your answer more complete :)

Comment: It would, but I've got no wish to steal your thunder; plus you deserve the rep for thinking of such a beautifully simple solution :)

Comment: this cannot be an answer ... what if a DOM has a empty class attribute like `<div class=""  id="asda"></div>`

Comment: @YoYo You made a good point here! I just check your answer, this has the same issue

Comment: @A.Wolff : yeah dude you are right ,, mine had the same problem so i deleted it... but +1 for your answer since i like the way you checked it

Answer (score 0):

Use `classList` property on the HTML Element:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").classList.length
document.querySelector("#mydiv").classList.length
$("#mydiv").prop('classList').length // jQuery method.
```

The `classList` gives the array of classes present for the element. So, `.length` will say if there's any class there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if `class` attribute:

- Present but no class( class="")
- Not present(undefined)

.

```
<div id="mydiv" class="">  // with class attribute but no class
<div id="mydiv">   // even without class attribute so no class

attr = $("#mydiv").attr("class")
hasClass = (attr == undefined || attr.replace(/\s+/, '') == "" )
```

Comment: what if i have `class="   "`  two space bar

Answer (score 0):

See working code snippet below:

```js
var elemClasses = $('body').attr('class') ? $('body').attr('class').split(/\s+/) : [];
if (elemClasses.length == 1){
  alert('Only one class');
}
else{
  alert('Element has ' + elemClasses.length + ' clases');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class=""></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to achive this.

```
var hasNoClass = !document.getElementById("#id").className;

if(hasNoClass){ /*...*/ }else{ /*...*/ }
```

Same approach using jQuery

```
var hasNoClass = !$("#id").className;

if(hasNoClass){ /*...*/ }else{ /*...*/ }
```

Comment: what if i dont have class attribute ?? :P

Answer (score -1):

Use this one...

```
var classes = $('#mydiv').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
```

This will give you an array of all the classes applied to your element.
For the length you can simply extend it as

```
var classes = $('#mydiv').attr('class').split(/\s+/).length;
```

Cheers

Comment: not an answer dude ,, it will COUNT  `1` if DOM has a empty class like `class=""`

Comment: @YoYo , thanks man, i've updated my answer because i had same bug !

Comment: Agreed.. Thank you. @YoYo

Answer (score -1):

You can do one thing take all class from the element then count the classes , try following code :-

```
var myClass = $("#mydiv").attr("class");
var myClassArray;
var myClassCount;

if (myClass != "")
{
    myClassArray = myClass.split(" ");
    myClassCount = myClassArray.length();
}
else
{
    myClassCount = 0;
}

console.log(myClassCount); // Number of class attached to that element
```

It may help you.

Comment: not an answer dude ... what if i have a attribute like `class="    "`  i mean double space :P